# Including PHP in XML

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to use PHP to get a customers name from the url

```
www.example.com/card/index.php?name=Fred
```

And use PHP to echo it in a xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
        <enable_music>true</enable_music>
        <music_path>music.mp3</music_path>
        <mute_button_visible>true</mute_button_visible>
<text_block>
<![CDATA[<font size="8" color="#B1FFF9"><br><br><br><br><font size="48" color="#B1FFF9">Dear <?php echo "test"; ?>!<font size="22" color="#B1FFF9">
<br>We wish you warm Christmas<br>and Happy New Year!
<br>Be happy and keep smiling!<br><p align="right"><font size="18" color="#4FCCFA"><br><a href="#" target="_blank">www.yourdomain.com</a></font></p>]]>
        </text_block>
    </config>
```

Above you can see that I am trying just to echo test just to get it working.

anything after the  nothing shows up including the echo

this file is called by a flash file (i included this info in-case its important)

thanks in advance

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: anything after the <?php echo "test"; ?> nothing shows up

Comment: Is your xml in .xml file?

Comment: Are you generating the xml file in PHP and then displaying it in a browser or are you trying to display an xml file with the PHP tags in it as above?

Comment: i am trying to display an xml file with the PHP tags in it as above as the flash file calls this file and cant edit that

Comment: It sounds like the web server doesn't recognise your file as a PHP file and therefore PHP ain't running. Your filename probably ends in .xml instead of .php

Comment: You could try setting your apache ( I presume ) server to process xml files as php though I think you'd be better using PHP to actually generate the xml file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using PHP to generate the XML as you go, the output of the call to DOMDocument can be either saved as a file or output as a string. In the exmple below it is simply returned as a string. The example tests for a GET parameter called `uname` - change that to whatever you want

```
<?php
        $uname=isset( $_GET['uname'] ) ? $_GET['uname'] : false;
        if( $uname ){
            $dom=new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
            $root=$dom->createElement('config');
            $root->appendChild( $dom->createElement('enable_music','true') );
            $root->appendChild( $dom->createElement('music_path','music.mp3') );
            $root->appendChild( $dom->createElement('mute_button_visible','true') );

            $text=$dom->createElement('text_block');
            $cdata=$dom->createCDATASection('
                <font size="8" color="#B1FFF9"><br><br><br><br><font size="48" color="#B1FFF9">Dear '.$uname.'!<font size="22" color="#B1FFF9">
                <br>We wish you warm Christmas<br>and Happy New Year!
                <br>Be happy and keep smiling!<br><p align="right"><font size="18" color="#4FCCFA"><br><a href="#" target="_blank">www.yourdomain.com</a></font></p>');
            $text->appendChild( $cdata );
            $root->appendChild( $text );
            $dom->appendChild( $root );

            echo '<textarea>'.$dom->saveXML().'</textarea>';
            $dom=null;
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['name']; ?>
```

Try by this way

Answer (score 2):

1. Is your file is `.php` file or `.xml` file? PHP script will not work in xml.
2. If it is PHP file then you may use `echo $_GET['name']`
3. But you have to use some `sanitize` in order to reduce the security risk like `sql injection`

Comment: sadly its a e-christmas card and uses a flash file that calls the config.xml do you know a way that i could include a file in xml like we can in php or is this not an option?

Comment: then of course it will not work. Can you call a php file from your flash scrip. If yes, then you can form a xml string inside php and return it

Answer (score 2):

You can create a .htaccess file in the same directory of your .xml file, then add the following line:

```
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml
```

This will mean that PHP will now run on .xml files in that directory when the webserver sends them.

Comment: i cant get echo $_request['name']to work but it will echo a word.

Comment: variable names are case sensitive $_REQUEST is not $_request